# Selecting associated id's when only IN (values) and NOT IN (otherValues)

Tags: sql, select

Sorry for the poor headline, I couldn't think of a better way to describe my problem, so I've made up for it by explaining it well with examples.

### Setup

If you'd like to follow along, here's the SQL to create the table for my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_sections` (`student_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (1,11);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (1,12);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (1,13);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (1,14);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (1,15);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,12);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,13);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,14);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,21);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,22);
INSERT INTO `student_sections` (`student_id`,`section_id`) VALUES (2,23);
```

This results in the following table:

```
| student_sections        |
|-------------------------|
| student_id | section_id |
|------------|------------|
| 1          | 11         |
| 1          | 12         |
| 1          | 13         |
| 1          | 14         |
| 1          | 15         |
| 2          | 12         |
| 2          | 13         |
| 2          | 14         |
| 2          | 21         |
| 2          | 22         |
| 2          | 23         |
```

### Scenario

I have a "group" of Sections for which I must find all Students associated with a combination of Sections. My application will have several "groups" of Sections.

For "Group 1" of section_id's: (11,12,13,14,15)
Student 1 is associated with all Sections (11,12,13,14,15).
Student 2 is associated with (12,13,14) but not (11,15).

For "Group 2" of section_id's: (21,22,23,24,25)
Student 2 is associated with (21,22,23) but not (24,25).

Given section_id's (12,13,14) I need to select the student_id's associated with those section_id's, but not with section_id's (11,15).

For example, if given section_id's (12,13,14) I want to select student_id (2). Even though student_id 1 is associated with section_id (12,13,14) she is also associated with 11 and 15, so I don't want her id returned.

The higher purpose of this query is I will use it as a subquery to select lists of students given a combination of sections.

Also for example, if given section_id's (12,13) no results would be returned.

### What I have tried

I tried using a mix of IN and NOT IN, but because 5 rows have student_id 1 and 3 rows associated with (12,13,14) the DISTINT() in the following query returns both student_id 1 and 2.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(student_id)
FROM
    student_sections
WHERE
    section_id IN (12,13,14)
    AND section_id NOT IN (11,15)
```

#### Update February 1

I added some additional use case data that slightly changed the requirements of the query. A Student will be scheduled against several "groups" of Sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For queries of this type, I recommend aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select ss.student_id
from student_sections ss
group by ss.student_id
having max(case when section_id = 12 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when section_id = 13 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when section_id = 14 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when section_id not in (12, 13, 14) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Here is a somewhat simpler version of the same idea:

```
select ss.student_id
from student_sections ss
group by ss.student_id
having count(distinct section_id) = 3 and
       count(distinct case when section_id in (12, 13, 14) then section_id end) = 3
```

I like the first version because it generalizes to many "groups within groups" problems.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: Thank you so much! While your solution does work, I do in fact need to specify the "NOT IN (11,15)" piece in some way. I will end up with additional `student_id` - `section_id` pairs for other "groups" of section_id's. So a student may be associated with section (12,13,14) for one grouping, they will also be associated with section (20,21,24) for another grouping. These additional pairings cause your suggestion to not work. Can you improve your answer? I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to INTERSECT two selects:

```
SELECT student_id FROM student_sections
WHERE section_id IN (12,13,14)
   INTERSECT
SELECT student_id WHERE
   section_id NOT IN (11,15)
```

Comment: From what I've researched, this would be perfect if I were using a RDBMS that supported `INTERSECT`, but I'm using MySQL which to my knowledge does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id
     , COUNT(*) x
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN section_id IN(12,13,14) THEN 'foo' END) y
  FROM student_sections 
 GROUP 
    BY student_id;
```

Comment: Yes. You do. But from there you also get to figure out the complete solution for yourself. :-)

Comment: Hey, it looks very nice. I was working on this question myself, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, but I like @Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT ss.student_id
FROM student_sections ss
     left join (select student_id 
                  from student_sections 
                  where section_id NOT IN (12,13,14)
                  ) s on ss.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE s.student_id is null
GROUP BY ss.student_id
HAVING Count(distinct ss.section_id) = 3
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77f96d/8).

Or using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT ss.student_id
FROM student_sections ss
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select null
  from student_sections 
  where section_id NOT IN (12,13,14)
    and student_id = ss.student_id
  )
GROUP BY ss.student_id
HAVING Count(distinct ss.section_id) = 3
```

Good luck.